# (Python) PyQtGui not updating GUI when clicked a button

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x

I have 2 radio buttons `selectDate` and `selectTime`. Under them are some widgets. I'm trying to make the widgets not grey out when the radio button above them is selected.

Python3.4 (Anaconda3 distribution), Windows 10 Pro 64bit, Qt4 64bit

Here is the code that checks if it's selected:

```
if self.selectTime.isChecked() == True:
        self.greyOut2(MainWindow)

if self.selectDate.isChecked() == True:
        self.greyOut1(MainWindow)
```

And here is the `greyOut1` and `2`. When executed they sucessfully grey out the widgets.

```
def greyOut1(self, MainWindow): #selectDate on
    print("go1")
    self.label_3.setEnabled(False)
    self.relativeTime.setEnabled(False)
    self.label_4.setEnabled(True)
    self.dateTime.setEnabled(True)

def greyOut2(self, MainWindow): #selectTime on
    print("go2")
    self.lebel_3.setEnabled(True)
    self.relativeTime.setEnabled(True)
    self.label_4.setEnabled(False)
    self.dateTime.setEnabled(False)
```

Now my problem is that the IF statments are getting executed only once so when you would select the button nothing would happend.

The program looks like this.

[image]

Here is the full (rusty) code (print is for debugging). This is my first GUI program and I'm learning Qt for a week now so please don't use advanced code.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(261, 371)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(261, 371))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(261, 371))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8("../Dropbox/python/gui/icon.png")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        MainWindow.setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(False)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(261, 371))
        self.centralwidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(261, 371))
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.action = QtGui.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.action.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(104, 60, 91, 22))
        self.action.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("action"))
        self.action.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.action.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.action.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.action.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.action.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 221, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 60, 51, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.groupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 241, 191))
        self.groupBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("groupBox"))
        self.selectTime = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.selectTime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 82, 17))
        self.selectTime.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("selectTime"))
        self.buttonGroup_2 = QtGui.QButtonGroup(MainWindow)
        self.buttonGroup_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("buttonGroup_2"))
        self.buttonGroup_2.addButton(self.selectTime)
        self.selectDate = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.groupBox)
        self.selectDate.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 110, 82, 17))
        self.selectDate.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("selectDate"))
        self.buttonGroup_2.addButton(self.selectDate)
        self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(116, 60, 61, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
        self.relativeTime = QtGui.QTimeEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.relativeTime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 60, 61, 22))
        self.relativeTime.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("relativeTime"))
        self.label_4 = QtGui.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 140, 21, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_4"))
        self.dateTime = QtGui.QDateTimeEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.dateTime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 140, 111, 22))
        self.dateTime.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dateTime"))
        self.forceCheck = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.forceCheck.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 300, 81, 21))
        self.forceCheck.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("forceCheck"))
        self.startButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.startButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 300, 71, 23))
        self.startButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("startButton"))
        self.label_5 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 330, 211, 20))
        self.label_5.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_5"))

        print(self.selectTime.isChecked())
        print(self.selectDate.isChecked())

        if self.selectTime.isChecked() == True:
            self.greyOut2(MainWindow)

        if self.selectDate.isChecked() == True:
            self.greyOut1(MainWindow)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Auto Shutdown", None))
        self.action.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Shut Down", None))
        self.action.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Restart", None))
        self.action.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Sleep", None))
        self.action.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "Log Off", None))
        self.action.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "Lock", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Please chose an action and then a time for it.", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Action:", None))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Time Schedule", None))
        self.selectTime.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Relative Time", None))
        self.selectDate.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Date", None))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "From now", None))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "On", None))
        self.forceCheck.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Force Action", None))
        self.startButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start", None))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Your computer will", None))



    def greyOut1(self, MainWindow): #selectDate on
        print("go1")
        self.label_3.setEnabled(False)
        self.relativeTime.setEnabled(False)
        self.label_4.setEnabled(True)
        self.dateTime.setEnabled(True)

    def greyOut2(self, MainWindow): #selectTime on
        print("go2")
        self.lebel_3.setEnabled(True)
        self.relativeTime.setEnabled(True)
        self.label_4.setEnabled(False)
        self.dateTime.setEnabled(False)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: On a side note, you don't need to pass `MainWindow` to your methods `greyOut`. It is only needed for `setupUi` and `retranslateUi`, the methods created by your Ui designer.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if/else` block is only executed once when the `setupUi` method is called.

What you need is signals and slots. From the [PyQt4 doc](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html):

> One of the key features of Qt is its use of signals and slots to
>   communicate between objects. Their use encourages the development of
>   reusable components.
>
> A signal is emitted when something of potential interest happens. A
>   slot is a Python callable. If a signal is connected to a slot then the
>   slot is called when the signal is emitted. If a signal isn’t connected
>   then nothing happens. The code (or component) that emits the signal
>   does not know or care if the signal is being used.

You can create you own signals, or use the ones already implemented.
The class `QRadioButton` already has four signals inherited from `QAbstractButton` (all the different buttons have those same signals).
The signals are `clicked`, `pressed`, `released` and `toggled` (see the [QT Doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#signals)). They are emitted when the user click on the button.

A radio button is checkable, so we can use the `toggled(bool checked)` signal. When the button is clicked, the signal is emitted with a boolean value: `True` is the button is checked, `False` if it is unchecked.
Here's a simple example:

```
self.radioButton=QtGui.QRadioButton()
self.radioButton.toggled.connect(self.on_radioButton_click)

def on_radioButton_click(check):
    if check:
        print("I'm checked !")
    else:
        print("I'm unchecked !")
```